# Logtalk and XPCE

Tags: user-interface, prolog, swi-prolog, xpce, logtalk

Can an application be developed using both XPCE and Logtalk, or are the class systems incompatible in some way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please, Logtalk, not LogTalk. Leave the Camel case to Java programmers :-)

You can use XPCE and Logtalk in the same application, with predicates in XPCE classes sending messages to Logtalk objects and predicates in Logtalk object and categories calling XPCE methods. There is also bundled support (with Logtalk) for using Logtalk message sending goals as XPCE call-backs goals (see the "xpce" example in the current Logtalk distirbution).

Comment: Thanks Paulo! Both for the answer and the spelling (fixed).